# How to remove a incorrect pathname from a GitHub repository?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, github, gitignore

If you take a look at [my repository or GitHub](https://github.com/CjStaal/ChatRoom-v3), you can see it has the path `/Documents/NetbeanProjects/`

I never had it do this before, *how can I configure Netbeans or GitHub to not include that?*
I don't know what I did for that to happen.

Comment: Hi, I tidied up your question a little, to make it more attractive to other users:

I added formatting around the directory name to highlight it, which makes it easier for people to read. I also got rid of the excess tags, as too many tags can turn people off. I also made the bare URL into a link.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it's not the files. The files are correct. I dont want it to have the /Documents/NetbeanProjects/ part in it.

Comment: Can you update the link? It is dead now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most probably been added and committed by you by mistake recently. To remove it, you can do

```
git rm --cached -r Documents/NetbeanProjects/REPONAME
echo "Documents/NetbeanProjects/REPONAME" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Removing Incorrectly corrected REPONAME and adding to gitignore"
```

---

***Edit***: You have created the repository in the incorrect directory, instead of creating it in `Documents/NetBeansProjects/reponame`, you have created it in the home directory.

So, re-create your repository in the correct folder and delete the current one using

```
rm -rf .git/
cd Documents/NetBeansProjects/REPONAME && git init
git add . && git commit -m "Initialising project"
```

Comment: Also, when I start a new project and then commit it and send it to a new repo on github, it sends ALL my projects =\ anything to do to help?

Comment: Also, the files are correct, it's the pathname that I don't want showing

Comment: The second part of this is the correct answer. Thanks :)